# Persistent localStorage in Awesomium

Tags: awesomium

We are using Awesomium (http://awesomium.com/) for a new project.

The problem is that when saving some data in localStorage in JavaScript it is not persistent. The problem appears when I close and reopen the application (on refresh I can fetch the data stored in localStorage).

I think that Awesomium stores the data somewhere in memory. Is there a way to make it store the data on disk?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Solved the problem using this code:

```
var webSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) , Awesomium.Core.WebPreferences.Default);
webControl.WebSession = webSession;
```

Answer (score 0):

Persistent localstorage is saved in cache folder and you can get this folder in debug folder of your Awesomium control